# Role of sorting algorithms in spite of having array.sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

1. Why do we need so many sorting algorithms to sort an array of integers when we have **array.sort**?
2. Is sorting different from finding the largest number in an array?
3. Which is the best sorting algorithm to sort an array ?

Comment: I can't answer your questions exactly but atleast i try.
1) Because there are different sorting techniques, some are multi threaded etc... and it always depends on the amount of numbers and your system and specifications which sorting algorithm you need.
2) yeah, there are also different finding algorithms. Also depends on system, specifications,..
3) Same as above. The best way is using an already sorted array and inserting the values at the right position.
Look at the different algorithms and their characteristics and deside for your problem which algorithm you should use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Any idea which algorithm does array.sort method internally use to sort an array ?

Comment: Take a look at the specifications (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte%5B%5D%29) --> Dual-Pivot Quicksort. You can also import the java sources into eclipse which will give you the possibility to inspect the source code of the java libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we need so many sorting algorithms to sort an array of integers when we have array.sort which already does the same?

Most programming languages ship with some sort of sorting algorithm in their standard libraries. Most of the time, you can just use this default sorting algorithm and you'll be fine.

That said, different sorting algorithms have different performance characteristics and different tradeoffs. Most library implementations of sorting algorithms use comparison sorts like quicksort, timsort, or introsort. These algorithms can be used to sort any objects that can be compared to one another, so they're good generic sorts. For certain cases - such as sorting integers - there are specialized algorithms that can take advantage of the fact that you're sorting integer data. If, for example, you're sorting an array with lots of small numbers in it, it might be faster to use counting sort or radix sort than quicksort, both in theory and in practice.

There are other considerations to take into account as well. Quicksort, for example, is fast on average but has degenerate cases. You might have applications where you absolutely cannot hit these cases, in which case using a custom sorting algorithm might be appropriate.

> Is sorting and finding the largest number in an array different ? i mean if an array is sorted obviously the largest number will end up at the end

Yes, these are different problems. You can find the largest element of an array in one pass over the array by simply recording the largest value that you've seen so far. This takes time O(n), uses space O(1), and is extremely efficient. Sorting algorithms need to spend more time and effort than this because they have to also find the *second*-largest element, the *third*-largest element, etc. In that sense, sorting is a fundamentally "harder" problem than the problem of finding the largest element of an array.

> which is the best sorting algorithm to sort an array ?

As I alluded to earlier, there is no one "best" algorithm to sort an array. It depends on many factors, such as what sorts of elements are stored in the array, what the distribution of those elements are, whether you want worst-case or average-case efficiency, how much memory you want to use, etc. As with most aspects of software engineering, there are lots of different tradeoffs to make, and it's up to you to choose which one you think is best.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

1. without a sorting algorithm you can't implement array.sort. It's like saying why do we need a cow when we can buy beef at the supermarket.
2. To find the max, you don't need to move the elements of your collection. To sort them, you need to move them around.
3. There is no "best" sorting algorithm. It all depends of your use case.

More : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: My question was rather like " why  do i have to take the trouble of milking a cow when i can buy it in the super market " :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need so many sorting algorithms to sort an array of integers when we have array.sort?

Each sorting algorithm has its pros and cons and its efficiency, both in terms of time and space, is going to be different depending on the context.

I suggest you take a look at [Big-O Cheat sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) which gives you a summary of the efficiency of each sorting algorithm (and link to those algorithms if you don't know them).

[image]

Your example, `Arrays.sort()` uses a quicksort behind the hood. It's pretty good in most of the cases but can be horrible (`O(n^2)`) in the worst case.

> Is sorting different from finding the largest number in an array?

Finding the greatest number is different than sorting the array. If you array is already sorted, the last number is the biggest and that's cool.
But if you just need the greatest, you don't have to rearrange the array and move all the elements in the right order, you can just read it. Reading the elements of an array and moving its elements doesn't have the same complexity!
The following code searches the biggest element and has a space complexity of `O(1)` and a time complexity of `O(n)`. It's easier than sorting an array.

```
int biggest = array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > biggest) {
        biggest = array[i];
    }
}
```

> Which is the best sorting algorithm to sort an array ?

There is no best sorting algorithm, it all depends on the context. I suggest that you read the [Sorting Algorithm wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and follow the links to understand better the behavior of each sorting algorithm, the importance of time/space complexity...

Answer (score 0):

1> Why do we need so many sorting algorithms to sort an array of integers when we have array.sort which already does the same...

Different sorting algorithm are being used for different type of use cases. So for e.g. Arrays.sort uses quicksort, while if your element count in array is less than 7 it uses insertion sort.

2> Is sorting and finding the largest number in an array different ? i mean 
if an array is sorted obviously the largest number will end up at the end

Yes you are right. Sorting your data has different purpose. If you want largest element you could always have find it with o(n) while if your dataset is already sorted you find it with o(1).

3> which is the best sorting algorithm to sort an array ?

It depends from use case to use case. Various factors like time/space comes into picture.

Answer (score 0):

1. Different problems call for different solutions. It depends on the nature of the array to sort which algorithm does the job best.
2. Finding the largest number requires only one walk through the array, which is more efficient then any true sorting algorithm can deliver.
3. See 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you** all for answering . 
I now understand that array.sort too uses one of these **sorting methods** and there is no **"best"** sorting method , it depends on the context .